# How to invert simple multiplication formulas

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am going back over my high-school maths education so that I can confer the benefits onto my programming. Working with trigonometry has caused me to wonder about a more basic set maths theory, which is this:

Supposing that `a * b = c`, and we have been given the real values of a and b, and we have to solve for c, it is simple what we must do:

```
a = 5
b = 10
c = a * b = 5 * 10 = 100
```

My question is specifically regarding the following...

Considering that we know that `a * b = c`, what formula must be used to work out the value of a, when we know b and c, and similarly, what formula must be used to work out the value of b when we know a and c?

```
b = 10
c = 100
a = [formula operating on b and c] = 5

a = 5
c = 100
b = [formula operating on a and c] = 5
```

Answer (score 1):

You have the following equation:
$$a\times  b=c$$
To get an explicit solution for $b$, all you need to do is divide both sides of the equality by $a$.
$$\frac{\color{red}{a}\times b}{\color{red}{a}}=\frac{c}{a}$$
$$\frac{\color{red}{a}}{\color{red}{a}}\times b=\frac{c}{a}$$
$$1\times b=\frac{c}{a}$$
$$\boxed{b=\frac{c}{a}}$$
From this, you can find the value of $b$ given values for $a$ and $c$.

---

To get an explicit solution for $a$, just divide both sides of the equality by $b$ and apply the same methodology:
$$\frac{a\times \color{red}{b}}{\color{red}{b}}=\frac{c}{b}$$
$$a\times \frac{\color{red}{b}}{\color{red}{b}}=\frac{c}{b}$$
$$a\times 1=\frac{c}{b}$$
$$\boxed{a=\frac{c}{b}}$$
Similarly, from this you can find the value of $a$ given values for $b$ and $c$.

Comment: Aha, so it could be said that to solve for the unknown variable, we divide the product of the original equation, c, by the known variable. Thanks for the detailed explanation. I am not sure I understand exactly why it is helpful to describe the sum in a verbose form such as `(a * b) / a = c / a`...is this a way to refactor more complex algorithms?

Answer (score 0):

You first set of displayed equations is wrong: 5 * 10 is 50, not 100.

In the second displayed set, your answer for $b$, namely, that's it's $5$, is also wrong, for if $b = 5$ then $c = ab = 5 \cdot 5 = 25$, rather than $c = 100$.

Anyhow, the formula you're looking for is this:

If $a * b = c$, then $a = c / b$ and $b = c / a$. Illustrated in your displayed form:

```
b = 10
c = 100
a = c/b = 100/10 = 10

a = 5
c = 100
b = c/a = 100/5 = 20
```

Comment: Whoops, that would explain why simple division of the two valued variables did not yield the result I expected it to. Somewhere along the line, I forgot my 10 times table! Maybe I should revisit primary school maths. :)